# storyboard views are not connected while using an iOS library

Tags: ios, xcode, github, storyboard, xlpagertabstrip

I am trying to implement a library(named: XLPagerTabStrip). Everything works fine with the help of this available tutorial [ https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip ].

**My problem is:** I can change my view controllers layout using code but i'm not able to change it through my storyboard; though the view controllers associated with the above library can be accessed. My storyboard views are well-connected with code.
Please help me get up from here. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution :**
Take the instance of the view controllers you wish to use inside MyPagerTabStripName( main controller class of library). In this way:

> override internal func
>   viewControllersForPagerTabStrip(pagerTabStripController:
>   PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {

```
    let firstVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myfirst") as! TabFirstViewController
    let secVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mysecond") as! TabSecondTableViewController
    return [firstVC, secVC]
}
```

Then you can access them using these identifiers in storyboard.